# How to edit this code to so that the results display in "sections" on the page

Tags: javascript

I am taking the output of the code below with these requirements:

- Display the results in "sections"
- Sections sorted from greatest to least number of duplicates.
- Use a variable to set how many sections are created
- Evenly divide array by "section" variable
- Place all remainders into the last section

When I am outputting the results to the page using the DOM. If the number of array elements is not evenly divisible by the sections variable number, I'm putting all of the remainders into the last section as depicted below. I am having trouble doing this entire task correctly.

(Note: I do not mean divs when referring to creating "sections". The desired outputs below should make things clearer.)

> Example array input
>   [4,4,4,4,2,4,4,4,4,4,2,2,2,3,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,7,3,3,3,1,6,6,1,1,1,1,1,7,7,7,7,6,6]
>
> Current Example output: 4 - 9 times, 2 - 8 times , 3 - 7 times, 1 - 6
>   times, 7 - 5 times , 6 - 4 times
>
> Desired Output: Example 1 (sections variable = 3):
>
> 4 - 9 times
>   2 - 8 times
>
> 3 - 7 times
>   1 - 6 times
>
> 7 - 5 times
>   6 - 4 times
>
> Desired Output: Example 2 (sections variable = 2):
>
> 4 - 9 times
>   2 - 8 times
>   3 - 7 times
>
> 1 - 6 times
>   7 - 5 times
>   6 - 4 times
>
> Desired Output: Example 3 (sections variable = 4):
>
> 4 - 9 times
>
> 2 - 8 times
>
> 3 - 7 times
>
> 1 - 6 times
>   7 - 5 times
>   6 - 4 times

My Code so far:

```js
const duplicateArr2 = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 100, 3, 5, 2, 5, 2, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23];

 const getStringOfDuplicated = array => {
          const hash = array.reduce((a, c) => (a[c] = ++a[c] || 1, a), {});
          return Object.entries(hash)
            .filter(([k, v]) => v > 1)
            .sort(([ak, av], [bk, bv]) => bv - av)
            .reduce((a, [k, v]) => [...a, `${k} - ${v} times`], [])
            .join(',   ');

        };


       document.getElementById("jsresultsoutput").innerHTML=getStringOfDuplicated(duplicateArr2);
```

```html
   <p id="jsresultsoutput"></p>
```

Comment: It would be much better to determine how far you are off if this is correct if it used the original data and produced the actual desired output example provided in the code part.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss is this comment for the OP or my answer?

Comment: @glhr The OP, your answer matches the OP's code which is why the comment is here

Comment: You here say `"I do not mean divs when referring to creating "sections" `- please include notes and an example of how, exactly with proper elements you would like the results to be presented if not in a "div" , you say DOM but that to me says "some type of HTML" - what would you like here? (for the formatted output)

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss I added that part to try to make thing extra clear. I used a p tag to display the elements to the page through the dom. Inside of the P tag used line breaks to divide and section visual content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check whether the number of array elements is evenly divisible by the number of sections using the modulo operator `%`.

Below is a working implementation. Here I'm setting the number of sections as a global variable, and I'm separating the sections using `<br>` (linebreak element in HTML).

Edit: separated the grouping calculation and formatting into two different functions. Modified implementation such that a maximum number of elements are put into the first `nGroups-1` sections (instead of only putting one element in the first `nGroups-1` sections).

```js
const duplicateArr2 = [4,4,4,4,2,4,4,4,4,4,2,2,2,3,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,7,3,3,3,1,6,6,1,1,1,1,1,7,7,7,7,6,6,55,55,67,67,45,54,45,54,100,100,200,200,300,300];

const getArrayOfDuplicated = array => {
 const hash = array.reduce((a, c) => (a[c] = ++a[c] || 1, a), {});
  return Object.entries(hash)
    .filter(([k, v]) => v > 1)
    .sort(([ak, av], [bk, bv]) => bv - av)
    .reduce((a, [k, v]) => [...a, `${k} - ${v} times`], [])
 };

// given a number of items to be sectioned into a certain number of groups
// returns a list of length nGroups with the number of items in each group
// such that at least (nGroups - 1) groups contain an equal number of items
// eg. getGrouping(10, 2) -> [5, 5]
// eg. getGrouping(10, 6) -> [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5]
const getGrouping = (nItems,nGroups) => {
 if (nGroups > nItems)
    return Array(nItems).fill(1);
  else if (!(nItems % nGroups))
    return Array(nGroups).fill(parseInt(nItems / nGroups));
  else {
    let numberOfEqualGroups = nGroups-1;
    var itemsPerEqualGroup;
    if (!(nItems % (nGroups-1)))
      itemsPerEqualGroup = parseInt(nItems / (nGroups - 1)) - 1;
    else
      itemsPerEqualGroup = parseInt(nItems / (nGroups - 1));
    equalGroups = Array(numberOfEqualGroups).fill(parseInt(itemsPerEqualGroup));
    remainder = nItems - itemsPerEqualGroup * numberOfEqualGroups;
    return equalGroups.concat(remainder);
  }
}
 
// takes an array and formats it into sections according to grouping
// returns a string with a newline after each line and two new lines between sections
const formatGrouping = (array,grouping) => {
  var outputString = ""
  var linesDone = 0;
  for (var section = 0; section < grouping.length; section++) {
   for (var line = 0; line < grouping[section]; line++) {
    outputString += array[linesDone] + '<br>';
      linesDone += 1;
    }
    outputString += '<br>';
  }
  return outputString;
};

var numberOfSections = 3;
result = getArrayOfDuplicated(duplicateArr2);
document.getElementById("jsresultsoutput").innerHTML = formatGrouping(result,getGrouping(result.length,numberOfSections));
```

```html
<p id="jsresultsoutput"></p>
```

Comment: This seems to create the proper groupings here.  I tested with 2-7 size and it works

Comment: Hi works great but doesn't work when I test it with this array for some reason, other than that it is great. Please try using the test array from my next message. Also, I would like the results to be distributed as evenly as possible between the sections. in the 4 sections example there were only 6 duplicates with 4 sections so this works, but when there are 13 duplicates with 4 sections I would like the output to have 3 duplicates in each section and the extra 13th duplicate in the final 4th section, so the 4th section would have a total of 4 duplicates in this example. Thank You.

Comment: const duplicateArr2 = [4,4,4,4,2,4,4,4,4,4,2,2,2,3,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,7,3,3,3,1,6,6,1,1,1,1,1,7,7,7,7,6,6,55,55,67,67,45,54,45,54];

Comment: @RobomanRobo I've updated the code in my answer, taking into account your feedback. Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

I'd divide that into two functions one of which groups your values into array of values & occurrences objects. The other function takes that array and the number of sections as arguments and distributes the objects properly.

```js
const input = [4,4,4,4,2,4,4,4,4,4,2,2,2,3,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,7,3,3,3,1,6,6,1,1,1,1,1,7,7,7,7,6,6];

const getOccurrences = (input) => {
  return input
    .reduce((acc, current) => {
      const occurrence = acc.find(el => el.value === current);
      if (occurrence) {
        occurrence.repeats += 1;
        return acc;
      }
      return [...acc, {
        value: current,
        repeats: 1
      }];
    }, [])
    .sort((a, b) => b.repeats - a.repeats);
}

const intoSections = (occurrences, sections) => {
  const mappedSections = {};

  if (occurrences.length % sections === 0) {
    let lastIndex = 0;
    for (let i = 1; i <= sections; i++) {
      mappedSections[`section_${i}`] = occurrences.slice(lastIndex, lastIndex + occurrences.length / sections);
      lastIndex += occurrences.length / sections;
    }
  } else {
    for (let i = 1; i <= sections; i++) {
      const members = i === sections ? occurrences.slice(sections - 1) : occurrences.slice(i - 1, i);
      if (members.length > 0) {
        mappedSections[`section_${i}`] = members;
      }
    }
  }

  return mappedSections;
}

const toString = (mappedSections) => {
  let result = '';
  for (const [sectionId, sectionMembers] of Object.entries(mappedSections)) {
    const members = sectionMembers.map(el => `${el.value} - ${el.repeats} times`).join('\n');
    result += `${sectionId}:\n${members}\n`;
  }
  return result;
}

const sections = 8;
const occurrences = getOccurrences(input);
console.log(occurrences);
console.log(toString(intoSections(occurrences, sections)));
```

Comment: This produces extra "sections" if the section number exceeds the groups available, for example if it is set to 8, it produces extra headings there.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```js
const duplicateArr2 = [4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 7, 3, 3, 3, 1, 6, 6, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 7, 7, 7, 7, 6, 6];

    const getStringOfDuplicated = array => {
        const hash = array.reduce((a, c) => (a[c] = ++a[c] || 1, a), {});
        return Object.entries(hash)
                .filter(([k, v]) => v > 1)
                .sort(([ak, av], [bk, bv]) => bv - av)
                .reduce((a, [k, v]) => [...a, `${k} - ${v} times`], [])
                .join(',   ');

    };

    // the output of your function was an object so I had convert it into an array

    var arr = getStringOfDuplicated(duplicateArr2).toString().split(','); 
    arr = arr.map(function(e){return e.trim();}); // trimmed whitespaces for each element
    sections = 5; // number of sections
    var length = arr.length;
    if(sections > length)
        sections = length;
    var no_of_elems = 0;
    var results = [];
    if (length % sections == 0) {
        no_of_elems = length / sections;
        for (let i = 0; i < length; i+=no_of_elems) {
            results.push(arr.slice(i, i + no_of_elems))
        }
    } else {
        no_of_elems = length / sections;
        remainder = length % sections;
        for (let i = 0; i < sections - 1; i++) {
            results.push(arr.slice(i, i + no_of_elems));
        }
        results.push(arr.slice(sections - 1, sections + remainder));
    }
    console.log(results); // desired result
```